# Вывод select с помощью js

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте! Есть такой код, который динамический выводит `input`:

```
var inputA = $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        name: 'answer',
        placeholder: 'Ответ',
        value: '',
        class: 'form-control',
        id:'answer',
        style: 'margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 15px'
        }).appendTo(div);
}
```

Нужно вместо `input` вывести `select` со значениями из бд. Код написал для примера

Answer (score 2):

Мало чем будет отличаться от того, как вы добавляете `input`.

Единственно что надо будет перебрать "значения из бд".

Например так:

```js
var data = { "1": "Раз", "2": "Два", "3": "Три" }; // Данные "из бд"

$('<select>').appendTo('div'); // Создаём пустой select
$.each(data, function(key, value) { // перебираем даные и создаём option   
     $('select').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value)); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```